# Insert text in left side on textbox - JS

Tags: javascript, telerik

**How Can I insert text in left side on textbox? Normally?**

Usually when I insert anything in html textbox the characters go in right side. I need implements this because I'll insert price.

Example (I'm using telerik mask this case):

```
....
<EditItemTemplate>
   <telerik:RadMaskedTextBox
       Mask="######,##"
       runat="server"
       ID="txtValue"
       Width="400px"
       MaxLength="15">
   </telerik:RadMaskedTextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
....
```

Comment: use css to align text left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CSS` class like this:

```
....
<EditItemTemplate>
   <telerik:RadMaskedTextBox
       Mask="######,##"
       runat="server"
       ID="txtValue"
       CssClass="left_align"
       Width="400px"
       MaxLength="15">
   </telerik:RadMaskedTextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
....
```

Css class:

```
.left_align{
    text-align:left;
    direction:ltr;
}
```

Comment: This way don't change nothin, but if I insert direction: rtl this case help me, but the mask invert too because of 'direction'. There is a way don't invert mask? Thank you!

Comment: @EricSaboia you should verify why this way did not change any thing by your browser `web inspector` tool (ctrl+shift+i)! Maybe you should use `text-align:left !important;` instead of `text-align:left;` in the `Css` class.